# How do you check if a password contains special characters and numbers?

Tags: python

```
import re

print("Your password must have lower and uppercase letters, may contain numbers and also must have at least 8 characters")
passWord = input("What is your password?: ")
special_chars = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

if len(passWord) >= 8:
    print("Your password is long enough!")
if passWord is not passWord.isupper() and not passWord.islower():
    passWord2 = input("Please re enter your password ")
    if passWord2 == passWord:
        print("Your password is valid")
    else:
        print("Oops, it seems your passwords don't match, please try again!")

else:
    print("You have made a mistake, please follow the rules that are shown at the beginning.")

if any(passWord.isdigit):
    print("Your password is Medium strength")
if(special_chars.search(passWord) >= 1):
    print("Your password is Medium strength")

if any(passWord.isdigit) and special_chars.search(passWord) >= 1:
    print("Your password is strong")
```

I am trying to check if this string contains special characters and numbers. If it has one or the other, it is medium strength. If it has both it is strong. I would expect the code above to work, but it does not. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `passWord is not passWord.isupper()`. `is` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably want `if passWord.isupper() or passWord.islower()`.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some sample inputs, what you expect the code to provide and what it's actually doing!

Comment: doesn't that make it so it can only be all uppercase or all lowercase? I want it so its forced to be a mix of upper and lowercase

Comment: `passWord.isdigit` also doesn't do what you think it does. You probably wanted `passWord.isdigit()`.

Comment: "any" just doesn't work this way and a regex "search" doesn't return a number. Play around a bit with the regex search in a Python shell to know what it returns if it does/doesn't find something and use it then.

Comment: It's something like 20x harder to brute-force an 11-character password known to consist solely of lowercase characters than an 8-character password that could consist of a mix of uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers. Don't underestimate the value of simply requiring a longer password, rather than lots of rules regarding what characters to use.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally advise against building your own security solutions, it would be best to offload this functionality to an external library that has been well-tested. Consider issues such as different languages (are Japanese hiragana special characters? Arabic numerals?).

However, you could use the `isalnum()` function:

```
>>> "hello".isalnum()
True
>>> "hello!".isalnum()
False
>>> "hello there".isalnum()
False
>>> "hello123".isalnum()
True
>>> "Hello123".isalnum()
True
```

If `passWord.isalnum()` is false, your password contains some kind of non-alphanumeric character.

There are other similar functions:

```
passWord.isalpha()
passWord.isnumeric()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a for loop that does what you're looking for:

```
teststring = "Thishas3#$&specialchars"

specialchars = '@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:'
howmany = 0
for i in range(len(specialchars)):
    char = specialchars[i]
    if char in teststring:
        howmany += 1
```

and even keeps a count of how many special chars are in a string.

Comment: Note you aren't using `i` for anything. Just write `for char in special_chars: ...`

Comment: good catch.  I didn't think I could iterate letters of a string like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
import re

def is_have_digits(passwd):
    return re.search('[0-9]', passwd) != None

def is_have_specials(passwd):
    return re.search(f'[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]', passwd) != None

passwd = "qwerty.123"
if is_have_digits(passwd) and is_have_specials(passwd):
    print("strong!")
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.